# Capture visible values from filtered range from a particular column in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

**Description**:
I have a sheet with about 30 columns and more than 500k rows on average (there are multiple files). Column 8 of the sheet holds filenames. I am applying filter on this column to only display rows with filenames that I want to see

**Goal**:
After applying the filter, I want to capture all visible rows in column 8 into an array. This is the bit I'm struggling with

**Code**:

```
Sub GetFilteredColumn()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim iLRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim aFilTags As Variant
    Dim oKey As Variant
    Dim oDic As New Dictionary

    With oWS

        ' Get row count of visible rows
        iLRow = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

        ' Check if any rows were returned after the filter
        If iLRow > 1 Then
            ' Get column 8 of the filtered range into an array
            ' ** THIS is where i'm trying to capture column 8 into and array **
            'aFilTags = .AutoFilter.Range
            'aFilTags = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
            aFilTags = .Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            ' Get unique values in dictionary
            For iRow = 2 To UBound(aFilTags)
                If Not oDic.Exists(aFilTags(iRow, 1)) Then
                    oDic.Add aFilTags(iRow, 1), aFilTags(iRow, 1)
                End If
            Next

            ' Display the unique list
            iRow = 0
            For Each oKey In oDic.Keys
                iRow = iRow + 1
                .Range("AZ" & iRow).Value = oDic(oKey)
            Next

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately I am not able to share the worksheet because of sensitive data in the workbook but happy to answer any questions. Thanks guys

Comment: hi, in For iRow = 2 To UBound(aFilTags)  shouldnt be   iRow = 2 To iLRow ?

Comment: @LuisCurado: either will work. I just used **UBound** because array is what I want to work with

Comment: in my case UBound(aFilTags) gives me 100000 lines.. and iLRow just 10... so the code seems to work. where do u have problems ?

Comment: @LuisCurado: It's when I'm trying to assign the column range to `aFilTags` as an array. So if I have 100k lines on my sheet and after filter I only have 5k visible rows.. I want the 5k visible rows in the array. At the moment, I'm getting 100k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
Set aFilTags = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each cl In aFilTags.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            cl = cl & ""
            If Not oDic.Exists(cl) Then
                oDic.Add cl, cl
            End If
Next cl
```

good luck

Comment: Perfect. This works. I've done it slightly differently but this works as well