# Set values of Excel range without clearing filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

So commonly I work with arrays because this speeds up processing in VBA. E.G.

```
'get data
values = dataRange.value

'Do some work on values array

'set data
dataRange.value = values
```

Recently we noticed that when doing the same process in Excel, on a Table with filters, Excel:

Performs the getter as we would expect by getting all the values:

```
'get data
values = table.DataBodyRange.value
```

Performs the setter starting at the first filtered row:

```
'set data
table.DataBodyRange.value = values 'Starts at the visible row?!
```

It does this even though `DataBodyRange.address` show the range is over all the data

Our current work around is to save the filter preferences, Clear the filter, set the data and then re-apply the filter. However this is slow, and seems pointless. Does anyone know of a more direct way to perform this job?

Work around code:

```
Sub Commit()
  'Create list object of HFRR.
  Dim lo As ListObject
  Set lo = Datasheet.ListObjects("<<TableName>>")

  'WORK AROUND:
  'In VBA range.value will only work if filters are NOT applied. I.E. we can't change the data model without first unfiltering the data.
  'This is a bad UX so the work around is to save the filters in a cache, and reload these after the data is set.
  'VBA doesn't provide a method of saving autofilter choices, so instead we use:
  '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter
  '=====================================================================================================================================
  'Save and clear filters
  Dim AutoFilterCache() As Variant
  SaveListObjectFilters lo, AutoFilterCache
  lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Set the data
    dataRange.Value = data

  'Restore the filters
  RestoreListObjectFilters lo, AutoFilterCache
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're doing some kind of processing with the data, wouldn't you have to reapply the filter anyways after you set the data back?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170675/3233363 ?  You can generate an array of visible cells that way (`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`); you could also capture your whole range +1 column, and in the extra column, loop back through your data and flag each visible row so only those are manipulated (if-statement).

Comment: @Cyril Yes, but then you have to update the areas. If you have an e.g. 300x30 array. And only rows 1-10 and 50-60 are showing, you need to do fairly complex array manipulation to produce 2 arrays, and then loop over all areas and apply the data. It just feels like there should be a more direct method. It is possible there isn't. But thought I'd ask...

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - Possibly, it depends on what is changing. Still re-applying the filters is faster than removing all filters and then re-applying them. Typically in more well designed frameworks you don't even need to re-apply the filters. This would be done automatically for you of course...

Comment: @Sancarn i guess my next question would be based on the filters... is there an issue with taking your array and doing check for the column based on the filter-criteria?  You then use one array, manipulate it, then paste back.  Since everything is done in memory, not referencing the sheet (once you've captured your array), it should be relatively quick.

Comment: (Ran out of space with this example)... Not wanting to make a mountain out of a molehill, but if you could build a simple userform which requests your filter-criteria, you could take those inputs and make changes, e.g., a date range in `textbox1` and `textbox2` would be `if arr(i,4) < textbox2.value And arr(i,4) > textbox1.value Then`

Comment: @Cyril I understand there are many workarounds to the problem. I was just mainly wondering if there was a more direct way of setting the data. The fact that the `setter` works differently from the `getter` is just... confusing and badly implemented by Microsoft... But there might be a more direct method of setting the data.

Comment: What did you end up doing given the [problems with restoring autofilter we both had encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850172/1026)?